# Remote VSCode extension not installing on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: vscode-remote

I am trying to download the remote development extension in vs-code released by Microsoft on a Ubuntu 18.04 Machine.

However the install fails and the following message appears:

`Unable to install because, the extension 'ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack' compatible with current version '1.34.0' of VS Code is not found.`

What could be done about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, this extension is in `Preview` mode. According to [VSCode Extension Page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack), you need to have Visual Studio Code **Insiders** in order to use this extension.

Comment: I installed VSC Insiders and now realize it's a completely different version of VSC. When I run VSC Insiders I am able to install Remote Development Extension Pack.